# cv2.imread: how to keep color channel when reading in grayscale image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.1

i am trying to load an grayscale image with opencv2, but somehow the color channel gets completely removed.

When i am doing:

```
img = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE, 1) // load image as rgb
```

`img.shape` returns for example `(28,28,3)`

But if i am loading the same image as grayscale:

```
img = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE, 0) // load image as grayscale
```

`img.shape` returns `(28,28)`, but i would expect/need a shape of `(28,28,1)`

Is this a bug in opencv or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can also use `np.expand_dims` besides what mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV does behave like that in Python when loading an image in grayscale. If you need to add on a channel in order to make it (28,28,1), you may do

```
import numpy as np
img = img[:, :, np.newaxis]
```